# How to check whether a bridge connected to physical interface?

Tags: centos, networking, bridge

In my CentOS 7.7 server, I use brctl show: there get 3 bridges:

```
[dele@att ~]$ brctl show 
bridge name bridge id       STP enabled interfaces
br-eb92c719d431     8000.0242d1ce907c   no      
bridge0     8000.000000000000   no      
docker0     8000.024216a07d31   no      veth73c744c
```

I want to know whether all the bridges is connected to the physical network interface, how to check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The interfaces column should show the interface associated with the bridge. You can also look the other way by running `ip a` and see if a physical interface has the bridge associated with it. In the example below, `brctl show` tells me that `brqadad232-a5` is associated with physical interface `enp65s0.31`. And when I look at `enp65s0.31` from `ip a`,  I see that bridge `brqadad232-a5` is associated with it.

```
$ brctl show
bridge name     bridge id               STP enabled     interfaces
brqadad232-a5          8000.0effcd8e7f9c       no              enp65s0.31

$ ip a | grep enp65s0.31
9: enp65s0.31@enp65s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 9000 qdisc noqueue master brqadad232-a5 state UP group default qlen 1000
```

When you run `brctl show`, the interfaces column may show non-physical interfaces, such as `tun` and `tap` interfaces. `veth73c744c` in your question is also an example of a non-physical interface.